# How to make an input have more than one event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button and a select in my form. The button has `onclick` event while the select has `onchange` event. How to make the select has both `onclick` and `onchange` event?

This is the script:

```
$('#i_btn').on('click', function(){
     alert('Event 1');
});

$('#i_sel').on('change', function(){
     alert('Event 2');
});
```

When the select is changed, it should do `alert('Event 1'); alert('Event 2');`. I do not want to rewrite the `onclick` code in `onchange`

Comment: `$('#i_btn').click()` in there... Of course, I would just make the function outside both handlers and reuse it.

Comment: @PHPglue I do not want rewrite the codes.

Comment: What does that mean? I guess you'll have to wait for another life, if you want the code to just magically work.

Comment: @PHPglue I do not want rewrite the `onclick` script on `onchange` script. The actual script has thousand rows. I guess you'll have to use your glasses when read a question.

Comment: Then put `$('#i_btn').click();`  inside your change Event, just like that. With no arguments that triggers a click.

Comment: @Shota when someone is trying to help you, it's best not to make snide/nasty remarks.  The statement "I do not want rewrite the codes" *states* that you do not want to make **any changes**.  It *appears* that you're *implying* it to mean that you don't want to *duplicate* the code, but that's not what it says and we can't infer your intention.

Comment: @freedomn-m then this line ( `I guess you'll have to wait for another life, if you want the code to just magically work`) is not needed I believe

Comment: @Shota I agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger the click event of #i_btn in the change event of #i_sel

```
$('#i_btn').on('click', function(){
     alert('Event 1');
});

$('#i_sel').on('change', function(){
     alert('Event 2');
     $("#i_btn").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Nice. This is what I'm looking for. Thank you mate. I'll accept it when it's allowed

Comment: I do not recommend this. This is much less maintainable and less readable.

Answer (score 3):

Write your events as separate functions :

```
$('#i_btn').on('click', event1);
$('#i_sel')
     .on('change', event1)
     .on('change', event2);

function event1(){
     alert('Event 1');
}

function event2(){
     alert('Event 2');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger inside the on change of the select make sure you have defined buttons on click before on change

```js
$('#btn1').on('click', function(){
     alert('Clicked');
});

$('#select1').on('change', function(){
     alert('Changed');
     $("#btn1").trigger("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button id="btn1">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply add the event handler to the element...

```
$('#i_btn, #i_sel').on('click', function(){
     alert('Event 1');
});

$('#i_sel').on('change', function(){
     alert('Event 2');
});
```

Unless you really need the click to trigger on the button...

Comment: This is not what the OP wants. He wants the event1 triggered when #i_sel changes. Not when it's clicked.

Comment: half the question asks how to add two events... And half asks how to run the same code... So I wanted to point this solution out just so they know their possibility